# How to write a macro to automatically create a frame with items in beamer?

Tags: beamer, macros

I want a definition like

```
\def\tag{......}
\def\printtag{......}

\tag{1.1}{
  title
  aa
  bb
  cc
}

\printtag{1.1}
```

to achieve

```
\frame{\frametitle{title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item aa
    \item bb
\end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a slightly adapted syntax (own argument for title and commas instead of line breaks, because TeX does not see line breaks):

[image: beamer]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\mytag[3]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname someframe:#1\endcsname{%
        \begin{frame}{#2}
            \begin{itemize}
                \forcsvlist{\item}{#3}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}}
}
\newcommand\printtag[1]{\csname someframe:#1\endcsname}

\mytag{1.1}{title}{
  aa,
  bb,
  cc
}

\begin{document}
\printtag{1.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, need "\usepackage{etoolbox}" ?!

Comment: @ZenoShuai Basically not, because beamer does load `etoolbox`. If you want to use this in other classes, then yes.